# How can I count the occurrence of adjacent elements in order in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, counting

I'm trying to count the number of equal adjacent elements in (list/string/whatever) from left to right.
any help?

for example)

```
1113322 would be [3,2,2]
3334555 would be [3,1,3]
```

forms of input and output can be anything (list, string..)
thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

sizes = lambda d: [len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(d)]

sizes("1113322")  # str, list, tuple, lazy iterator, whatever
# [3, 2, 2] 
sizes("3334555")
# [3, 1, 3]
```